# Range.Autofill methode in vba. set the destination to Lastrow in VBA

Tags: excel, autofill, vba

Hi I have the following code which works ok. My question is how can I set the destination for auto fill to Range(selection, LastRow) instead of 
Range(selection, selection.End(xlDown). because this does the autofill for the entire column even does areas that there is no information in it it fills them with 0.

```
Sub usingfind()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim oWkSht As Worksheet
Dim PWkSht As Worksheet
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim c As Date
Dim myCell As Range
Dim Home As Range
Dim Sgf As Range
Dim Vracht As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim j As Long

Set oWkSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Registration")
LastColumn = oWkSht.Range("A" & Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
LastRow = oWkSht.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
c = Date

Set myCell = oWkSht.Range("1:1").Find(What:=c, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)

If Not myCell Is Nothing Then
    myCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(New_Order!RC[-41]:RC[-39])"
    myCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.FillDown

End If

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `range(mycell.offset(1),cells(lastrow,mycell.column)).formular1c1 "=SUM(New_Order!RC[-41]:RC[-39])"`

Comment: Thank you for your response

Comment: Hi SJR, I have one more question. do you know how I could  adjust this line ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(New_Order!RC[-41]:RC[-39])"  with this                                                       Sheets("New_Order").Range(n & LastRow) + Sheets("New_Order").Range(O & LastRow) + Sheets("New_Order").Range(p & LastRow)